# Swift selectors: how to construct instance referring to method with parameters?

Tags: swift, reflection

I'm using Swift and Objective C's reflection to try to invoke a method, but the method accepts arguments and I can't work out how to construct an instance of `Selector` which refers to a method which accepts arguments.

Here is some sample code:

```
class Thing : NSObject {

    func doSomething() {
    }

    func doSomething(str :String) {
    }

}

extension Thing {

    func doSomethingElse(str :String) -> String {
    }

}

let t = Thing()

var selector = Selector("doSomething")
//selector = Selector("doSomething:")

if t.responds(to: selector) {
    t.perform(selector)
}
```

So I can invoke `doSomething` with no problem, but I cannot seem to create a `Selector` from a string which refers to `doSomething(str :String)`. I attempted do to so with the string "doSomething:" (the commented out line).

Just in case it makes any difference, I'm ultimately attempting to invoke the extension method `doSomethingElse`.

How can I invoke Swift methods with arguments via reflection/selectors?

P.S. I'm aware that in general you're supposed to use `#selector` nowadays, but this won't work in my case because the method `doSomething` might not exist in the compiled code.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C land a Swift method with the signature "doSomething(str :String)" is called "doSomethingElseWithStr:".